# initialisms‎ vs acronyms vs abbreviations

Tags: abbreviations, acronyms, initialisms

What is the difference between these **initialisms‎** vs **acronyms** vs **abbreviations**?
As I understand from SO:

```
initialisms‎ are like BOA,USA(i.e. letter by letter).
acronyms are like NASA, AIDS(i.e. words).
```

> than what is abbreviations?

Comment: In ordinary speech, most people don't distinguish between "initialism" and "acronym". Most people say "acronym" for both, and most people have never even heard the word "initialism". The distinction is rather fussy, mainly of interest to grammarians.

Comment: Related question on ELU: english.stackexchange.com/questions/3755/difference-between-an-acronym-and-abbreviation.

Answer (score 1):

An [abbreviation](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abbreviation) shortens one word or a short sequence of words to one or a few letters. A few random examples:

- *misc.* for *miscellaneous* (abbreviation)
- *Dr* for *doctor* (contraction)
- *HTML* for HyperText Markup Language (initialism)
- *sonar* for *sound navigation and ranging* (acronym)
- *etc.* for *et cetera*
- *Sat.* for *Saturday*
- *LOL* for *laughing out loud*
- John *F*. Kennedy (or *JFK*) for John *Fitzgerald* Kennedy
- ...

As you can see, in the **wider** definition abbreviations encompasses *contractions* ("dropping letters from the middle of a word", *acronyms* and *initialisms* (using the first letter(s) of a multi-word phrase) and *abbreviations* in the **stricter sense**, which are defined as "dropping letters from the end of a word".

Comment: So what's the difference between acronyms and initialisms?

Comment: @Kreiri: Initialisms use the first letters and pronounce them letter-by-letter: Chief Executive Officer shortens to CEO and reads "ce-e-oh". Acronyms use sometimes more than one letter of each word and form new "words", see "sonar" in the answer above. Also note that those two are not mutually exclusive: The ICE train is in the US spoken like the frozen water but originally stands for "Inter City Express".

Comment: The rule for an an initialism becoming an acronym is one of convenience and familiarity. Ice is a familiar word, and ICE slips easily into acronym. Likewise, long initialisms are extremely rare, and almost invariably are rejected in favor of acronyms. The cutoff point seems to be about 3 letters. While the FTC (Federal Trade Commission) is pretty well fixed, the President of the United States  is (when abbreviated for convenience) POTUS, pronounced "poe - tuss".

Comment: My understanding has always been that an acronym must be pronouncable, whereas an initialise is pronounced letter by letter.