# Would this be considered as a proper acronym?

Tags: acronyms

I know acronyms are like abbreviation of words. For example, **LASER** would be **Light Amplification by Simulated Emission of Radiation** and **SCUBA** would be **Self Contained Underwater Breathing Apparatus**.

So, I came across an acronym **CIBER** as in **Collaborative Initiative for Bee Research**. I do not see where the *E* in that acronym comes in but I could guess that it came from **BEe**.

I have been taught that in acronyms, one letter should only represent only one word. Would **CIBER** be accepted as a proper acronym? If so, is there a rule that I am not aware of?

Comment: Would this help: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/57122/initialisms-vs-acronyms-vs-abbreviations/57126#57126 (possibly a duplicate?)

Comment: @Stephie ah sorry no. I have viewed that question in advance of posting this and thought that it is different. I am looking for whether two letters in an acronym can represent a word and if so, whether it would be considered as a proper one.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acronym) (highlighting by me):

> An acronym is an abbreviation, used as a word, which is formed from the initial components in a phrase or a word. **Usually these components are individual letters (as in NATO or laser) *or parts of words or names* (as in Benelux).** There are broad currents of consensus but no universal standardization of various names for such abbreviations and of their orthographic styling. [...]

So according to this, your CIBER (Collaborative Initiative for Bee Research) is as much of an acronym as *Benelux* (Belgium, Netherlands & Luxembourg).